# need some help about deleting an element from a dictionary which is inside of a list

Tags: python

I want to delete an element of a list which contents are dictionaries

I've created a function called "del_product(product):" and tried many ways to delete the element, but it ends up in KeyError

```
def del_product(product):
    found=False
    for lis in productos:  
        for dic in lis.values(): 
            if product in lis.values(): 
                flag=True                
                del(lis[product])
        return lis

    print(f"{product} deleted successfully") if found==True else print("{product} not found")
```

I expect the output of the function works properly about deleting the element, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: Perhaps show some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right format when call a dictionary value is: `dict[key]`, you're calling `dict[value]` instead. That is the reason why you got `KeyError`.

You should provide data samples and expected output for getting a faster response.

This is my example based on your code:

```py
productos = [{"key1":0, "key2":1}, {"key1":0, "key2":"pro"}]
def del_pro(val):
    for dic in productos:
        for k in dic.keys():
            if dic[k] == val:
                print(dic)
                del(dic[k])
                return dic
```

```py
>>>del_pro("pro")
{'key1': 0, 'key2': 'pro'}
{'key1': 0}
>>>productos
[{'key1': 0, 'key2': 1}, {'key1': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to make `found = True` before you delete your item, but instead you're referencing a different variable name called `flag`. There may be other issues, but the biggest one I see here is setting `flag` to `True` instead of `found`.

Additionally, you are wanting to print something when done, but you're print statements come after the `return` operator. Calling `return` will exit your function. This means that the print statements can never be reached.

So, in conclusion, change `flag` to `found`, and then move your if/else print statement to *before* you `return lis` or else those prints will not be able to execute.